# DropDownList selects first item in list when the selected item is the last item in the list on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select

I am having a problem with my `DropDownList`.

The list is working fine until I select the last item in the list and click the button to do the post back. Once the postback occurs the selected Item in the list is changed to the first item.

All the other items in the list work fine and stay selected.

The List is generate inside of an `if (!IsPostBack)`

There is no other code controlling the selected item of the list.

To fix this I added a blank list item to the end of the list and it seems to fix the problem.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    List<RolesWithPermissions> lstPerms = Utility.loadRolesAndPermissions();

    foreach (RolesWithPermissions perm in lstPerms)
    {
       drpUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem(perm.userRole, perm.userPermissions));
    }
    drpUsers.Items.Add("");
}

protected void dtnEditPerms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string permissions = drpUsers.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

These are the only sections in the code behind that interact with the drp down list that is causing problems.

Here is the drop down list code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpUsers" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: It is probably something to do with your code.  Why don't you edit your post and add your code.   PS:  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I added the code that propagates the drop down list and the click even that is resetting the drop down back to the first item.

Comment: Interesting -- Where is the if(!IsPostBack) code? Is it in Page_Load()?

I just created a quick site with a dropdownlist that I populated using hard coding (addItem("Test1")) etc. in the Page_Load on !IsPostBack.

I used a button to read the text from the DDL and it worked fine.

Are you sure all your data is valid? Are there any nulls in perm.UserRole for instance?

Comment: Could you also show the markup for your `DropDownList`?

Comment: yes the !IsPostBack is in the Page_Load. And all data is returning correctly. It's just odd. now adding the blank listItem the last item in the list (blank one) still stays selected on post back.

Comment: It seems that it is working now after I added the blank list item and then took the code back out and am no longer creating it.  Very strange..